# Angular - Prevent (ngModelChange) from being called on HTML render

Tags: angular

currently using Angular 6

I have some HTML markup that looks like this:

```
<div *ngIf="isOnline">
  <input [ngModel]="selectedEscrowOffering" (ngModelChange)="onChangeEscrow($event)"/>
</div>
```

and a function on the `.ts` file

```
onChangeEscrowDropdown($event) {
  console.log($event, "was returned");
}
```

When I modify the `isOnline` variable from `false` to `true`, `onChangeEscrow` gets triggered returning a value of `undefined`

How do I stop Angular from triggering `ngModelChange` on rendering of HTML that references the function?

Comment: It shouldn't being triggered. See [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uceqwn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). BTW, you mistyped `[ngModel]`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
<div *ngIf="isOnline">
  <input [ngModelChange]="selectedEscrowOffering" (ngModelChange)="$event && onChangeEscrow($event)"/>
</div>
```

This will execute `onChangeEscow` only when `$event` is truthy

Answer (score 1):

have you considered using `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf` ?

I haven't tried it myself yet, but since the object is not being destroyed or created when you hide it (unlike using `*ngIf`) it's reasonable to expect it wouldn't trigger binding events

```html
<div [hidden]="!isOnline">
  <input [ngModelChange]="selectedEscrowOffering" (ngModelChange)="onChangeEscrow($event)"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to fully use reactiveForms.  With this markup...

```
 <form [formGroup]="issuerDetails" 
   <div class="form-group">
     <input formControlName="escrowOffering"> 
   </div>
</form>
```

You get the value by `this.issuerDetails.value.escrowOffering`.

If you need to capture when that value changed

```
this.issuerDetails.get('escrowOffering').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  console.log('The value of escrowOffering changed to', val);
  this.doOtherThing(val);
});
```

Personally, i prefer using Reactive Forms to ngModel almost always.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had my code running in a reactive-form earlier, didn't post the entire code snippet.

ReactiveForms and templateForms `(ngModel)` don't play well together.

My form binding variable and ngModel variable were pointed to two different things `escrowOffering` and `selectedEscrowOffering`.

FormControl caused a lifecycle event change to the ngModel as a result:

```
<form [formGroup]="issuerDetails" 
   <div class="form-group">
     <input 
     formControlName="escrowOffering" 
     [ngModel]="selectedEscrowOffering" 
     (ngModelChange)="onChangeEscrowDropdown($event)"> 
  </div>
</form>
```

ngModel conflicts with the `formControl` in how values are set, so I did the following:

- Remove `formControlName` from the HTML
- Added `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` -> this makes form control ignore this HTML
- Added the formControl binding in the callback, since we're still using reactive-forms

final code below:

```
 <form [formGroup]="issuerDetails" 
     <div class="form-group">
       <input 
         formControlName="escrowOffering" 
         [ngModel]="selectedEscrowOffering" 
         (ngModelChange)="onChangeEscrowDropdown($event)"> 
     </div>
 </form>
```

This is what the new callback function looks like, the `ngModelChange` updates the `formControl` now

```
onChangeEscrowDropdown($event){
    this.issuerDetailsForm.escrowOffering.setValue($event);
}
```

### Additional Notes

Code sandbox here isolating just `ngModel` and the `isOnline` variable by itself, does not trigger lifecycle hooks

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcsmux?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Also, alternatively I could have removed `ngModel` entirely, and used reactive forms only. `ValueChanges` could have been used to watch for changes

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/valuechanges-in-angular-forms/